# Microsoft KB2673642 won't install for VS 2008 despite having all pre-requisites

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, azure-devops

I'm current attempting to update VS 2008 to allow me to access my company's new TFS 2012 instance after a recent migration.

Unfortunately, I receive the following message despite meeting all prerequisites:

```
None of the products that are addressed by this software update are installed 
on this computer. Click Cancel to exit setup."
```

I have all of the prerequisites (VS 2008 SP 1, VS 2008 Team Explorer, and .NET 2.0 SP 2) installed.

Here are the product details from my installation of Visual Studio 2008:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1

Installed Edition: Professional

Microsoft Visual Basic 2008   91605-270-6373342-60975
Microsoft Visual Basic 2008

Microsoft Visual C# 2008   91605-270-6373342-60975
Microsoft Visual C# 2008

Microsoft Visual C++ 2008   91605-270-6373342-60975
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer   91605-270-6373342-60975
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer
Version 9.0.21022.8

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office   91605-270-6373342-60975
Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Tools for Office

Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008   91605-270-6373342-60975
Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008

Crystal Reports    AAJ60-G0MSA4K-68000CF
Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008


Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB2538241)   
KB2538241
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2538241.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB944899)   
KB944899
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944899.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB945282)   
KB945282
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945282.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946040)   
KB946040
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946040.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946308)   
KB946308
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946308.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946344)   
KB946344
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946344.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB946581)     
KB946581
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946581.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947171)   
KB947171
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947171.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947173)        
KB947173
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947173.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947180)   
KB947180
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947180.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947540)   
KB947540
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947540.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB947789)   
KB947789
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947789.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB948127)   
KB948127
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948127.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB953256)   
KB953256
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled     
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953256.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB971091)   
KB971091
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971091.

Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB973674)   
KB973674
This hotfix is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this hotfix will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973674.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB945140)     
KB945140
This service pack is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this service pack will be uninstalled      
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945140.

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB947888)   
KB947888
This service pack is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this service pack will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947888.

MySQL Connector/Net   6.1.4
Data design and management tools for MySQL.  Copyright © 2007-2009 MySQL AB

Process Editor WIT Designer   1.4.0.0
Process Editor for Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server, Version 1.4.0.0

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU 
(KB2251487)   
KB2251487
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be 
uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2251487.

Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU 
(KB2669970)   
KB2669970
This security update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell (integrated mode) - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this security update will be 
uninstalled automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669970.

SQL Server Analysis Services   
Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services Designer 
Version 10.0.1600.22

SQL Server Integration Services   
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )

SQL Server Reporting Services   
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers 
Version 10.0.1600.22

Team Foundation Server Power Tools   October 2008
Power Tools that extend the Team Foundation Server integration with Visual Studio.

Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB956453)   
KB956453
This update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this update will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956453.

Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB967143)
KB967143
This update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this update will be uninstalled 
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967143.

Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU (KB972221)   
KB972221
This update is for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU.
If you later install a more recent service pack, this update will be uninstalled
automatically.
For more information, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972221.

WSPBuilder
WSPBuilder Visual Studio AddIn
http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder
GPL Lincens
```

Comment: This might help you: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f1f9dc0f-449e-4d87-a104-36dbed84384d/vs2008-sp1-installation-keep-failing-whats-wrong?forum=vssetup

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I gave it a try, but it did not cause any change in result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.

Reinstallation of VS2008 SP1 was the solution for me.  No need to remove, just re-run the SP1 installer and then KB2673642 VS2008 Compatibility Pack will go through.